# shader graph always displaying a pink texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

[image: this is what the shader graph looks like. It should just display whats behind it if my knowledge about shader graphs is correct.]
I am definitely quite new to shader graphs, or just shaders in general. I had decided to follow a tutorial by code monkey to try and figure out shader graphs but havent been able to make it past step one due to this. It should just be transparent. the video tutorial link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IC5JoS0wX0s)

EDIT 1:
So, I am now using the URP. It is no longer a pink sphere, but a grey one. Still not transparent though, but at least it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Are you using URP? Meaning do you have a URP asset referenced in the Graphics settings (see [URP - Getting Started](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/InstallURPIntoAProject.html))

Comment: Going into the Shader Graph Editor and then in graph settings, changing "Active Targets" to include both "Universal" and "Built In" works for me.

Comment: I just recently started working with shaders and I see my colors change from editor to runtime ...so perhaps your colors will change in runtime. They're odd and nonsensical. I definitely recommend finding non-youtube tutorials.

Comment: @Marcus , your suggestion works. But why does it work?